# Qubes (Fedora 23) won't login

Tags: fedora, xfce, xen, qubes, sddm

I have been using Qubes 3.2 for 5 months now without any significant problems. Then, **out of nothing**, I can't login. Qubes passed to `sddm` login screen as usual, then I could choose from desktop environments and type password but, after I did this, cross cursor `x` showed up and nothing more happend. It's not frozen, I can still switch to `tty` and login there, but even no ethernet controller has been loaded. Creating new user did also nothing.

Some time ago I answered a question here regarding exactly the same scenario on standard **fedora 24** but that steps won't work for me neither. I believe someone ever solved that as **it happend *twice*** to me (fedora support forums are still ignoring this).

Note that I has been using Qubes clean install,

- no testing repos enabled
- domains and dom0 were up to date
- 5 months without a bug

Qubes 3.2 is based on fedora 23 and xen kernel...
Any fresh idea will be awesome as I have to boot an less secure OS now and don't have time and handy tools to secure it myself.

---

**Current Qubes version is 4.0.1, problem solved.**
Still curious tho.